# How to create new page can get custom field other post in wordpress

Tags: customization

I want to create a new page eg: example.com/demo/2222

in which: demo is a page, 2222 is id of a post.

This page can retrieve data from the custom field of post 2222

when i change 2222 to other id post, custom field also change same.

hope everyone can help me :) Thanks

Comment: Just `var_dump( $_GET );` on your page and you should see the `2222` there in your template. Try to look around on this site to see how you alter the main query using `pre_get_posts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible, but it's to hard to do that, becouse you should make a rewrite rules for pages..

Easiest way is to make url something like: `example.com/demo?post_id=2222`

then you can get `post_id` like these: `$post_id = (int) $_REQUEST['post_id'];`

and pass it to some function to get custom field atc..

Comment: thanks, i mean rewrite rules for the page. I'm not an expert, so you can help me? :(